# Album art on MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` to play my podcast. I was wondering if there is a way to add an Album Art instead of having the default Quicktime logo.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `view` from the `MPMoviePlayerController` instance. Try adding a new subview (say, `UIImageView`) with the AlbumArt.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the album art of playing track like so.

MPMediaItem *item = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
MPMediaItemArtwork *art = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];

Hope this helps